# C++ A function does not work in while(GetMessage(...)){...}

Tags: c++, winapi, while-loop, sendmessage

I was really ridiculous. While I was doing C++ programming, there was a need to wait for a long time.  So I decided to use `while(){...}`.

**Mode 1 :** If I use `while (1) {...}`,
the CPU will be under the greatest load. (It takes maximum load on one CPU.)

**Mode 2 :**

```
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Will reduce the load on the CPU.
However, there is a big difference in the execution of statements between `while(1){...}` and `while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){...}`.

For example,

**Mode 1**

```
dwEndTime = time(NULL) + 120;
while(1)
{
    if(IsOutOfTime())
        break;
}
```

And

**Mode 2**

```
dwEndTime = time(NULL) + 120;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)
{
    if(IsOutOfTime())
        break;

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

**Implementation of `IsOutOfTime()`:**

```
BOOL IsOutOfTime()
{
    if(time(NULL) >= dwEndTime)
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

Results in different execution results. `break` is not working in **Mode 2**.

Someone please help me to solve this problem.

If I give `Sleep(...)` in `while (1) {...}`, I can reduce the CPU load, but I hate coding style like this.

**1.** What intrinsic differences between **Mode 1** and **Mode 2**.
**2.** Did I misuse **Mode 2**?
**3.** How can I reduce CPU load not using `sleep`.

Comment: "Mode 1", besides being a busy-wait that wastes CPU cycles, also will make your Windows program unresponsive.

Comment: When you say that `break` is "not working", do you mean that you have determined that `IsOutOfTime()` is true but the loop doesn't terminate or do you mean something else? What is the definition of `IsOutOftime`?

Comment: Why these modes? What is it that you really trying to do? What is the underlying issue?

Comment: I also recommend you read [the documentation for `GetMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) and how it behaves.

Comment: @molbdnilo, Apologize, When the time is over, `IsOutOfTime` returns `TRUE`. I will post implementation of `IsOutOfTime`.

Comment: I think you need to use [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`WM_TIMER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-timer).

Answer (score 3):

Both mode 1 and 2 should be avoided if possible, because both poll to check if you're out of time.

Mode 1 takes 100% cpu and won't handle any Windows messages.
Mode 2 only checks for timeout when a message is received, so it can miss timeouts for a while.

Instead, you should look into using a [timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592(v=vs.85).aspx) which will trigger when you're out of time. `GetMessage` will return a `WM_TIMER` message when the timer has expired. (I am assuming that `IsOutOfTime` simply checks that some time has passed).

Comment: If you don't have a message loop to process `WM_TIMER` messages with, you can use a [waitable timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

WinAPI contains some functions that allow to wait for an event, the `WaitForSingleObject`, `WaitForMultipleObject` functions (and their `...Ex` extension. Such a wait does not stress the CPU because the process is in wait state.

If you have a GUI program and wants to keep it responsive, you should use the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` function in a loop. If you need to wait for one single objects, it gives:

```
DWORD cr
while ((cr = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &handle, FALSE, milli_sec_timeout, QS_ALLINPUT)) {
    if (cr == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        // event has been signaled process it
        break;
    }
    else if (cr == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1) {
        // something has arrived in the thread event loop: process the message
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else if (cr == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        // timeout has elapsed
        ...
    }
    else { // abnormal condition, see doc for more
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that overkill? What's the advantage over the `SetTimer` approach? Still upvoted.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: The main difference if that SetTimer only combines a timeout and a message loop, while `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` may way for other processes and threads, console input, mutexes, events, etc.

Comment: Problem: When another nested message loop is started while a message is processed, you won't notice the timeout until that loop ends. Say a dialog box is opened or the user is dragging a window around, all these create nested message loops.

Comment: [_"Why bother with RegisterWaitForSingleObject when you have MsgWaitForMultipleObjects?"_](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081117-00/?p=20183/)

Comment: @SergeBallesta, How can I check the time is out?

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* way to make a thread wait for a given period of time is to use [`Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep):

```
Sleep(1000 * 120);
```

But be aware that the calling thread will be completely blocked while sleeping.  If you call that in a GUI thread, the GUI will be frozen until the sleep is done and control returns to the GUI message loop.

In that case, you can use [`SetTimer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) and have your GUI message loop handle `WM_TIMER` messages as needed.

Another option is to use a [Waitable Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012.aspx) instead, eg:

```
HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
liDueTime.QuadPart = -10000000 * 120;
SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE);

// wait for hTimer to be signaled...

CloseHandle(hTimer);
```

In a GUI thread, you can use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` to wait for the timer to signal while still servicing GUI messages, eg:

```
HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
liDueTime.QuadPart = -10000000 * 120;
SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE);

bool keepLooping = true;
do
{
    DWORD ret = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &hTimer, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLINPUT);
    if (ret == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        // timer elapsed ...
        break;
    }

    if (ret == (WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1))
    {
        MSG msg;
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                PostQuitMessage(msg.wParam);
                keepLooping = false;
                break;
            }

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
}
while (keepLooping);

CloseHandle(hTimer);
```

If you don't need to handle GUI messages while waiting on the timer, then you can use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) or [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025.aspx) instead (depending on whether you are waiting on just the timer by itself, or waiting on other objects as well):

```
HANDLE hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
liDueTime.QuadPart = -10000000 * 120;
SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, FALSE);

WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(hTimer);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, since you seem to be struggling with [`SetTimer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which looks like the best solution here), I will post full source code for you.  It really is very simple, please stop messing about with busy loops.

Note: this code doesn't need a window but it does need an event loop (but you seem to be OK with that).

Setup:

```
VOID CALLBACK MyTimerProc (HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime);
DWORD dwTimerID = SetTimer (NULL, 0, 120 * 1000, MyTimerProc);  // 2 minute timeout
```

Message loop (do NOT test for your timeout in here):

```
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)
{
    TranslateMessage (&msg);
    DispatchMessage (&msg);
}
```

Timer proc:

```
VOID CALLBACK MyTimerProc (HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    KillTimer (NULL, dwTimerID);
    // Do whatever it is you wanted to do when your timeout elapsed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. `while(GetMessage(..)){..}` is **BLOCKED**.
I have used `GetMessage()` in `while(...)` badly.
Because, if there is no message to translate and dispatch, `GetMessage` will be **block** until any message occurred.
So, I implemented my code like this.

```
#define MESSAGE_NOT_OUT_OF_TIME WM_USER+1
#define MESSAGE_OUT_OF_TIME WM_USER+2

PostMessage(NULL, MESSAGE_NOT_OUT_OF_TIME, 0, 0);

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)
{
    if (MESSAGE_NOT_OUT_OF_TIME == msg.message)
        IsOutofTime();

    if (MESSAGE_OUT_OF_TIME == msg.message)
        break;

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Implementation of `IsOutofTime()`

```
VOID IsOutofTime()
{
    if(dwEndTime <= time(NULL))
        PostMessage(NULL, MESSAGE_OUT_OF_TIME, 0, 0);
    else
        PostMessage(NULL, MESSAGE_NOT_OUT_OF_TIME, 0, 0);
}
```

Although the `CPU`load is about 70 ~ 80%, I have found the reason and solved the problem.

Comment: I tested your code, it works well but the load of CPU is about 10.2 (Maximum ~12.4%), on 8 CPUs.

Comment: The code is incomplete. I assume that `IsOutofTime` posts either `MESSAGE_OUT_OF_TIME` or `MESSAGE_NOT_OUT_OF_TIME` to the message queue? In that case, this is just another busy-wait polling solution that will eat up CPU cycles unnecessarily.

Comment: Just what is wrong with using a timer, or perhaps waiting on a waitable object as suggested above?  What does `IsOutOfime()` actually _do_?.  You should stop hacking around and learn how to solve this problem properly.

Comment: @PaulSanders I know that this solution is not good. But I kept and solved `while(GetMessage(...){...}` not using `Sleep`. So, I posted this solution. I can appreciate that this solution is not good, but don't Down-Vote me.

Comment: I think the best way is to use EVENT to check the time is out.

Comment: What makes you think that?  It's certainly not the way I would do it.   Please see my answer. It's about half a dozen lines of code, go with it.